# using bash/node to retrieve command output

Tags: node.js, bash

I'm attempting to create part of a build script that creates a file containing information about the git repo. How do i get the result of 2+ commands as a string.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var cmd = 'echo $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)|$(git log -1 --format=%cd)|$(git rev-parse HEAD)';

exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  fs.writeFile("src/test.js", stdout, function(err) {
      if(err) return console.log(err);
      console.log(stdout);
  });
});
```

I know the problem is in my `cmd`. I just don't know what it should look like to get a string like `<branch>|<date>|<commit-hash>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the argument you're passing to `echo` isn't quoted. After your `git` subcommands are evaluated, the command you're executing looks like this:

```sh
echo my-branch-name|Mon Dec 5 09:23:00 2016 -0600|d1a9da04125fd67edea6062e99d0be960220d2a4
```

The shell is correctly interpreting the pipe characters here as, well, pipes. In other words, it thinks you want to pipe the output of `echo my-branch-name` to a command called `Mon` and so on. You could fix this by adding quotes around the argument to `echo`:

```js
var cmd = 'echo "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)|$(git log -1 --format=%cd)|$(git rev-parse HEAD)"';
```

I tried this locally and it wrote the following to the file:

```
my-branch-name|Mon Dec 5 09:23:00 2016 -0600|d1a9da04125fd67edea6062e99d0be960220d2a4
```

**Edit:** This doesn't work with bash on Windows, apparently because [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) uses `cmd.exe` by default. It may be possible to point it at bash with the `shell` option, but instead changing the command to the following worked for OP:

```sh
var cmd = 'bash -c \'echo "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)|$(git log -1 --format=%cd)|$(git rev-parse HEAD)"\'';
```

Comment: that command works if i run it directly in my terminal. It does not work if i put it in my script and run it, `node write_git_info.js`. It literally puts `"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)|$(git log -1 --format=%cd)|$(git rev-parse HEAD)"` in the file. There's no eval going on.

Comment: doing it as @chepner said, only outputs the last command. I'm looking for some string concatenation.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was hasty in adopting @chepner's approach. I've reverted that part of my answer. I tried it just now in the `node` REPL and it works exactly as indicated.

Comment: i'm using git bash and this doesn't seem to work. See this gist https://gist.github.com/dadamssg/bacaddff95734b8d1073a493e41ba447. `test.js` is the output of running the other file.

Comment: That's odd. What version of Node? I pasted the code from your gist into a file and ran it and got the expected output.

Comment: using node v5.0.0

Comment: That's very strange. I just installed v5.0.0 and it worked the same. Does it help if you add `{ shell: true },` before the callback (`exec(cmd, { shell: true }, function...`)?

Comment: Oh. That's a pretty relevant detail. If you're on Windows, `exec` will execute the command using `cmd.exe`, not bash, [per the docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback). If you have bash installed you need to tell it to use that instead, which I suppose would look something like `{ shell: '/path/to/bash.exe' }`.

Comment: got it to work with this https://gist.github.com/dadamssg/2f6cc9f8aee4bbbc3e8c32c3c5988c79. If you want to update your answer with this i'll mark yours as correct. otherwise i'll just delete the question. Thanks!

Comment: Could you humor me and let me know if either of these work? 1. `{ shell: 'bash' }`, or 2. `var cmd = 'bash -c \'echo "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)|$(git log -1 --format=%cd)|$(git rev-parse HEAD)"\'';`.

Comment: @David Great! I've edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need command substitution. Just pipe the output of one command directly to the next.

```
var cmd = 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | git log -1 --format=%cd | git rev-parse HEAD';
```